# What does "There exists a $\nu$ -almost everywhere uniquely determined family of probability measures $\mu_x$" mean?

Tags: probability, analysis

For disintegration theorem in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem,
[image]

I am confused what does
"There exists a $\nu$ -almost everywhere uniquely determined family of probability measures $\mu_x$" mean?

Comment: Let's use as an example the unit square, with the two-dimensional measure $\mu(x, y) = 4xy$. The DT says that we can slice that up into a family of measures $\mu_x(y)$ such that $\mu(x, y)$ is a scaling of $\mu_x(y)$, where the scaling is given by $\nu(x)$. In this case, the natural assignment is $\mu_x(y) = 2y$ and $\nu(x) = 2x$. Note, however, that since $\nu(0) = 0$, we can write anything we like for $\mu_0(\cdot)$, so the "almost everywhere" is relative to the support of $\nu$; this would be true even if $\nu(x) = 0$ on a set of non-zero measure.

Comment: (cont'd) However, we can, additionally, put in arbitrary measures on a set of $x$ of measure zero without affecting the disintegration property, even where $\nu$ is not zero—hence "$\nu$-*almost* everywhere".

Comment: BTW I'm being sloppy, $\mu_x$ is really a function in this case on the unit square, not the unit segment; it's just that it's intended to be zero (almost) everywhere but in the relevant slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of the sentence  "*There exists a $\nu $-almost everywhere uniquely determined family of probability measures $\mu _x$*" is:

1. there exists a family of probability measures $\{\mu _x\}_{x\in X}$ (satisfying certain properties described in the link), and
2. for any other family of probability measures $\{\mu '_x\}_{x\in X}$ satisfying the same properties above,  one has that
   $\mu '_x=\mu _x$, $\nu $-almost everywhere in the sense that set $\{x\in X: \mu '_x\neq \mu _x\}$ has $\nu $-measure zero.

Answer (score 2):

It is a family of measures $\{\mu_x:x\in X\setminus N\}$ indexed by a set such that $\nu(N) = 0$.

In the disintegration theorem, think of a linear surjection $\pi:\mathbb R^2 \to l$ onto a fixed line $l$, and the Lebesgue measure $m$. **For $\nu:=\pi_*m$-a.e. $x$,** the measure $m_x$ is the "natural" Lebesgue-measure (or unambiguously, $\mathcal H^1$) supported on the line $l^\perp$ orthogonal to $l$, intersecting the point $x$, and we can integrate functions
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^2} f\,m(dx) = \int_l\int_{x+l^\perp}f(y)\mathcal H^1(dy)\, \nu(dx).
$$
The family of measures here is $\{\mathcal H^1|_{x+l^\perp}:x\in l\setminus N\}$ for some set $N\subset l$ of $\nu$-measure $0$.

I like to think of disintegration as putting measures on almost all the leaves of a foliation of $Y$ by level sets of $\pi:Y\to X$, in such a way that I can integrate functions $f$ on $Y$ by integrating over almost all the the parameters $x\in X$, $f|_{\pi^{-1}(x)}$.